# How to transfer PSQL users and roles to another database

Tags: postgresql

Is it possible to copy an identical PostgreSQL setup to another computer running the exact same OS version?
The main thing I am interested in is copying the users, groups, and roles without having to manually create them one by one in the new system.

PSQL version: 9.4 running on Debian Linux

Comment: Hi, and welcome to dba.se. If I were you, I'd shutown the instance, copy the files over with the same file paths (including any startup/shutdown files in the systemd setup) and restart? Never done it, but it might be an easy way if you can shutdown the cluster for the time it takes to copy the cold instance?

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but: Postgres 9.4 is [no longer supported](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/)  you should plan an upgrade as soon as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `pg_dumpall` for this:

```
pg_dumpall --globals-only -U postgres -f roles.sql
```

This will put the definition of all roles (=users and groups) as well as any tablespaces into the output file. You have to use the superuser (typically `postgres`) for this.

Then run the generated `roles.sql` using `psql` on the other computer.

Comment: Any thoughts on my proposal? Reasonable or ridiculous?

Comment: Well that would copy everything including the data, but the question asks for "*copying the users, groups and roles*"